# Zeroing channels of cut out area

Tags: gimp

I imagine there is probably going to be an easy solution for this in GIMP, but I for the life of me can't figure it out.

I'm using the `color picker` tool with the `use info window` selected to verify pixel values.

Basically, I have some pixels in an image that I need to zero out. By that I mean I want the RGBA values to all be set to 0.

I attempted to:

1. use the `rectangular select tool` to select the group of pixels
2. use bucket fill to set the pixels to black with opacity set to 0.0
3. Then, to verify it was done correctly, I use the `color picker` to test the value of the rectangle I just filled.

Unfortunately, it seems to just contain the previous value. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "opacity" of the bucket-fill is the opacity of the paint, not the opacity of the resulting pixels. In other words the less opaque it is, the less visible the result. What you want to do is bucket-fill selection with black, then [delete].